# How to scroll the scrollview bases on UITextView content size in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uikit, uitextview

I am adding a scrollview on `UIViewController` and also I have added content view on that scrollview.

After that I have added a textview on content view and textdata is coming from services.

Here my main requirement is scroll content size need to set according to text data size but according to my code contentview is scrolling too much but I have to scroll the contentview based on textdata size, please help me.

Clearly this `UITextView` behaviour i.e `UITextView` is scrolling up to textdata content size.

## my code:-

```
    #import "ViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController ()

    {
        UITextView * TextView;

        UIScrollView * scrollView;
        UIView * containerView;
    }

    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
        scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

        containerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [scrollView addSubview:containerView];

        NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView,containerView);

        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollView(600)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

        TextView = [[UITextView alloc]init];
        TextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        TextView.text = 
    //Applying autolayouts for textview1
        NSLayoutConstraint * constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TextView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:20.0f];
        [containerView addConstraint:constraint2];

        constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TextView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:5.0f];
        [containerView addConstraint:constraint2];

        constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TextView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:-5.0f];
        [containerView addConstraint:constraint2];

        constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TextView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:1000];
        [containerView addConstraint:constraint2];


 [scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[containerView(==scrollView)]|"
                                                                           options:0
                                                                           metrics:nil
                                                                             views:views]];

        [scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[containerView(1200)]|"
                                                                           options:0
                                                                           metrics:nil
                                                                             views:views]];
    }
```